# PHAdjustmentData is nil in "startContentEditingWithInput"

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension

I'm working on a photo-editing extension app, and I want it to be able to save the information about the changes made into the PHAdjustmentData, so that user can modify those changes later. I save all the required data into PHAdjustmentData, however, next time I edit the image - PHAdjustmentData is nil.
Here is a sample code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) PHContentEditingOutput *output;

- (void)startContentEditingWithInput:(PHContentEditingInput *)contentEditingInput placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
{
    self.output = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc] initWithContentEditingInput:contentEditingInput];

    // here contentEditingInput.adjustmentData is always nil
}

- (void)finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(PHContentEditingOutput *))completionHandler
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
    [dict setObject:@"value2" forKey:@"key2"];
    NSData *adjData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict];
    PHAdjustmentData *phAdjData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc] initWithFormatIdentifier:@"ident" formatVersion:@"1.0" data:adjData];
    self.output.adjustmentData = phAdjData;

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(result, 1.0);
    [data writeToURL:self.output.renderedContentURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

    completionHandler(self.output);
}
```

How do I save the adjustment data properly, so that I can access it next time user edits the image? Thanks!

Comment: Did you implement [`canHandleAdjustmentData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHContentEditingController_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/PHContentEditingController/canHandleAdjustmentData:) and return YES upon detecting your own adjustment data format?

Comment: That was it. When I just created the project, I set the canHandleAdjustmentData to return NO, and then totally forgot about it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. Moving the solution to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhotoKit gives you adjustment data in `startContentEditingWithInput` only if you've agreed to handle that data. You agree by implementing  [`canHandleAdjustmentData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHContentEditingController_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/PHContentEditingController/canHandleAdjustmentData:) to check the format identifier and version of the adjustment and then return true for formats you can handle.

If you return false from `canHandleAdjustmentData`, then you'll get a nil adjustment data in `startContentEditingWithInput`. Not only that, you'll also get a pre-edited version of the photo image, so you can't work off of how it looked before the last edit.